# send parameter from a ps1 to other ps1

Tags: powershell

I have a file called file.ps1 with the following code:

```
$varsent=$args[0]
echo $varsent
```

when I tried to call this ps1 file with the following command because I need execute ps1 with elevated rights:

```
$var = "test"
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-noprofile -file "\\network path with spaces\file.ps1" $var ' -verb RunAs
```

Result is the word "$var" instead "test"

But with

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-noprofile -file "\\network path with spaces\file.ps1" test ' -verb RunAs
```

result is word "test"

I think that problem is that $var is not replaced by its value when code is executed but I do not why. Please, can you help me? I must use $var.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `$var` is not interpreted inside single quotes strings, try :

```
$var = "test"
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-noprofile -file \\path\file.ps1 $var " -verb RunAs
```

With spaces :

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-noprofile -file `"C:\temp\Un petit test.ps1`" $var" -verb RunAs
```

``" allow you to use `"` inside `""`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply @JPBlanc. Now a new windows powershell ISE is opened and closed inmediately after enter credentials. Would be because \\path\file.ps1 include spaces and was inside single quotes? I edited my question.
I also tried to add a new variable with the path, but it seems that argument list only works with double quotes :(
`$var = "test"
$Ps1Path = "\\network path with spaces\file.ps1"
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-noprofile -file $Ps1Path $var " -verb RunAs`

Comment: If you've got spaces in your file path you have to keep using "", I edit my answer.

Comment: I LOVE YOU @JPBlanc. Will you marry me? Thanks, thanks, thanks and **thanks again**!!!